# Using ROS for telecomumication

Tags: ros, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm using ROS with LAN network to connect my devices in my project. However, now I would like to configure my system out of LAN network. I want to set up a computer to run the Master node and connect to this computer from anywhere that have internet connection. Anyone experiences this kind of problem with ROS? Can you please give me a suggestion to do it?

Thanks

Haquang

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34519/using-ros-for-telecomumication/) by [haquang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1292/haquang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Accessing all your ROS nodes that run in a local network from the outside might be tricky since you needed to run everything with a public IP.

I guess one option would be to use a VPN. You can have a VPN server that is publicly available and connect to it from the outside to get into your local network. OpenVPN is easy enough to set up and works quite well.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-25**:
We use openvpn in the standard PR2 operation for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basic information for such a setup is available on the ROS Wiki. Take a look at setting up multiple machines at http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines. As long as you have persistent connectivity over your network, using one master should work fine.

If you need to run too many nodes across this one master, and notice problems launching new nodes, then you might have to use a multimaster setup. With persistent connectivity, the current [multimaster stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/multimaster) should work well enough.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1